# Get checkbox value from HTML in Angular 2 typescript.

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, typescript

I have two checkboxes in my html as follows:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /> Folder 1: </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /> Folder 2: </label>
```

but I'm unsure of how to retrieve the checkbox values inside my Typescript file. I know I can accomplish this by calling a separate function for each checkbox and changing a value within my typescript. However, that doesn't seem like the best way - if I had ten different checkboxes then I would need 10 different functions in my typescript.

Is there a simply way to get whether the checkbox is on or off based on the id? Is there a better way than that?

Comment: Can you post your component's class code? I think you should use angular data binding on the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to two-way-bind the checkbox, you should use ngModel binding.

```
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkBoxValue" />
```

and in your component's class:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  checkboxValue: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: Added this and got the following error: 'Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. I've imported FormsModule in my class.

Comment: You should import FormsModule in your NgModule imports, not only in your class.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html#!#two-way-binding

Comment: It does not work if you don't set the "name" attribute. 
No idea where to find the Angular version I'm using, probably Angular 5 (fresh .Net project started 2 months ago).

Answer (score 2):

you may bind to checked property of `input` element like below,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <label><input type="checkbox" [checked]="checkbox1" /> Folder 1: </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" [checked]="checkbox2" /> Folder 2: </label>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
  checkbox1 = false;
  checkbox2 = true;
}
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nS2ef1LdoILv1T8mD81y?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The Plunker is no longer working.  Gets an error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading https://unpkg.com/rxjs/operators.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[value]="myVariable"` in checkboxes!